# Saving Core Data MOC in Main Thread Only, Yet Deadlocking

Tags: core-data, deadlock, nsmanagedobjectcontext

To verify that I am saving only in the main thread, I added a log statement to the single MOC save method that is called.

In my app I decided that, instead of diving into managing and merging two Core Data MOCs for multiple threads, I could get by with processing just file information from the file system and passing these non-managed objects to the main thread, where this info would then be used to save data to managed objects.

The MOC is accessed through a category on NSManagedObject.
There are blocks (ASIHTTPRequest started block) that call save on the MOC, the source states that they are always called on the main thread.

Thread dump shows deadlock info as '__psynch_mutexwait + 26', right after the save call to NSManagedObjectContext.

I feel that I may be misunderstanding something fundamental.. :(

MORE INFO EDIT: I call dispatch_get_main_queue() to call a function that contains a call to NSManagedObjectContext save. I think that because it is executing on the main thread, that this should be fine.

MORE MORE INFO EDIT : I can trigger the deadlock faster by scrolling through the NSFetchedResults controller's table view of NSManagedObjects that are being manipulated often. In this case, it locks on the fetch request.

SELF-SOLUTION EDIT : The problem was that I was executing a FETCH request simultaneously on two threads. My assumption that multi-threaded reading was OK, was wrong.

Comment: I believe you get a lock when you execute GCD block with `dispatch_get_main_queue()` on main thread. You can always check if you are running on main thread: `if ([NSThread isMainThread]])`and then do the appropriate calls.

Comment: That is good to know, I checked and I'm not doing that. I think the problem is that I am incorrectly assuming that concurrent read-only operations are OK. I will implement multiple managed object contexts, yay!